# Web site Bot access - Out of memory: Kill process (apache2) score or sacrifice child

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, security, bots, load-balancing

I have a web site hosted in Amazon EC2 t2.large instance and usually it's memory requirement is 3 GB, but sometimes when some bots access the site, it become unavailable. When I check the kernel log I found this issue recorded.

```
Out of memory: Kill process 31741 (apache2) score 22 or sacrifice child
```

This was running on t2.medium and I upgraded to t2.large expecting this will resolve the issue.

I've updated my robots.txt file as below.

```
User-agent: * 
Crawl-Delay: 5

User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /img/

User-agent: SemrushBot-SA
Disallow: /

User-agent: SemrushBot-BA
Disallow: /

User-agent: SemrushBot-SI
Disallow: /

User-agent: SemrushBot-SWA
Disallow: /

User-agent: SemrushBot-CT
Disallow: /

User-agent: SemrushBot-BM
Disallow: /

User-agent: SplitSignalBot
Disallow: /

User-agent: dotbot
Disallow: /

User-agent: Mail.RU_Bot
Disallow: /
```

This is a PHP based system. From AWS side also I have added a load balancer, WAF and Bot control as well. Still I am facing this issue.

Could you please help me on this.

1. Is there any way to restrict all bot requests except google and facebook
2. How can I protect my web site from a DDOS attack

Really appreciate if someone can give me guidance on solving this issue.

Comment: Do you use CloudFront and WAF?

Comment: I am using AWS WAF